# How to replace level 2 in a multiIndex dataframe with values from a regular dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, overwrite

I am writing an algorithm for processing customers at work for some data analysis, and I am grouping the data by user ID as my level 1, then by month for my level 2.

I am then doing some processing work on the data user by user, which involves a monthly time series.

The code I have below does exactly what I need it to do, save for the final step.

**How can I overload the data in my original with the processed time series data in the output?**

```py
    tempDF1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=[0,1], parse_dates=[1], thousands=',')
    
    tempDF1["Average"] = 0
    tempDF1["Score"] = 0
    
    for id, df in tempDF1.groupby(level=0):
        for date in df.loc[id].index:
            df.loc[(id,date),"Average"] = df.loc[(id,date)].Purchased/df.loc[(id,date)].Count
            df.loc[(id,date),"Score"] = df.loc[(id,date)].Count/10*log(df.loc[(id,date)].Average, 10)
        try:
            list(df.loc[(id,"2021-01-01",),:])
        except:
            df.loc[(id, "2021-01-01",),:] = 0
        try:
            list(df.loc[(id,"2023-06-01",),:])
        except:
            df.loc[(id, "2023-06-01",),:] = 0

        resampleDF = df.loc[id].resample('M', closed="left").mean().fillna(0)
        print(resampleDF)
        tempDF1.loc[id].replace(resampleDF, inplace=True)
        print(tempDF1)
```

Below is the sample output from the code above.  The **resampleDF** is for ID 1785 and I am trying to replace the whole level; level 2 indexing, the data in the columns, everything wholesale.  I need to put **resampleDF** into **tempDF1** in place of what is there for 1785 (and the rest, but that should be accomplished by the above loop.

**resampleDF**

| Month | Count | Purchased | Average | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-02-28 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-03-31 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-04-30 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-05-31 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-06-30 | 1.0 | 9999.0 | 9999.0 | 0.399996 |
| 2021-07-31 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-08-31 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-09-30 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |
| 2021-10-31 | 2.0 | 20.0 | 10.0 | 0.200000 |
| 2021-11-30 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.000000 |

**tempDF1**

| user_id | Month | Count | Purchased | Average | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1785 | 2021-06-01 | 1 | 9999 | 0 | 0 |
|  | 2021-10-01 | 2 | 20 | 0 | 0 |
| 1857 | 2021-06-01 | 1 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 1953 | 2021-03-01 | 5 | 250 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023 | 2021-09-01 | 5 | 1100 | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 18149 | 2023-03-01 | 1 | 300 | 0 | 0 |
| 18169 | 2023-03-01 | 2 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 18177 | 2023-03-01 | 2 | 1100 | 0 | 0 |
| 18210 | 2023-03-01 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 18215 | 2023-03-01 | 2 | 110 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

With the dataframes you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

tempDF1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "user_id": [1785, 1785, 1857],
        "Month": ["2021-06-01", "2021-10-01", "2021-06-01"],
        "Count": [1, 2, 1],
        "Purchased": [9999, 20, 100],
        "Average": [0, 0, 0],
        "Score": [0, 0, 0],
    },
).set_index(["user_id", "Month"])

print(tempDF1)
# Output

                    Count  Purchased  Average  Score
user_id Month
1785    2021-06-01      1       9999        0      0
        2021-10-01      2         20        0      0
1857    2021-06-01      1        100        0      0
```

```py
resampleDF = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Month": [
            "2021-01-31",
            "2021-02-28",
            "2021-03-31",
            "2021-04-30",
            "2021-05-31",
            "2021-06-30",
            "2021-07-31",
            "2021-08-31",
            "2021-09-30",
            "2021-10-31",
            "2021-11-30",
        ],
        "Count": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0],
        "Purchased": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0],
        "Average": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0],
        "Score": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.399996, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
tempDF1 = pd.concat(
    [
        resampleDF.assign(user_id=1785).set_index(["user_id", "Month"]),
        tempDF1.drop(index=1785),
    ]
)

print(tempDF1)
# Output

                    Count  Purchased  Average     Score
user_id Month
1785    2021-01-31    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-02-28    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-03-31    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-04-30    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-05-31    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-06-30    1.0     9999.0   9999.0  0.399996
        2021-07-31    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-08-31    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-09-30    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
        2021-10-31    2.0       20.0     10.0  0.200000
        2021-11-30    0.0        0.0      0.0  0.000000
1857    2021-06-01    1.0      100.0      0.0  0.000000
```